# docker-compose exit code 243 on node v18.4.0

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

When I try to deploy a container using docker-compose, I get the following error:

```
testing    | 
testing    | > test@1.0.0 start
testing    | > npm-run-all --parallel start:server
testing    | 
testing    | 
testing    | ERROR: "start:server" exited with 243.
testing exited with code 1
```

This only happens on any [node:18.4.0](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/main/16) images. I have to use that node version.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.4.0-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

CMD npm start
```

My docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  testing:
    container_name: testing
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    ports:
      - 80
      - 9009:9009
```

My app (index.js):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

My package.json

```
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:server",
    "start:server": "nodemon .",
    "start:web": "echo web starting"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

os: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
docker-compose: version 1.29.2
docker: Docker version 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu2~20.04.1

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you found the problem, but this can help someone:

I was havin the same issue using `node:bullseye` image that comes with `npm v8.13.0`, so I updated it to the latest version (v8.15.1, in my case) an it was solved.

So, to keep using this image with the latest version, i put this in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a volume mapping onto the `/app` path. That hides everything in that path in the image, including the npm packages you install when building your Dockerfile.

Also, your port mappings don't match your app. Your app listens on port 3000, so your should map port 3000 to a host port.

If you use this docker-compose file, it'll work.

```
version: '2'
services:
  testing:
    container_name: testing
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Then you can go to http://localhost:3000/ and you'll get your "Hello World!" message.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, In your `index.js` you exposed port 3000 `const port = 3000`.

But on docker you exposed 80 and 3009

```
ports:
      - 80
      - 9009:9009
```

A tip - you don't have to `COPY ./package.json .`, you copied the entire folder into the container.

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80

CMD npm start
```